# Валидация/маска для телефонного номера

Tags: javascript, html, валидация

Делаю `input` для телефона. Но номера могут быть и не Российские... Начал разбираться какие вообще они бывают.

Начинаться должны (в идеале) с плюса `+` и кода страны.

Дальше скобки и вот тут кстати я видел разные версии: например когда плюс с кодом страны вносится в скобки, типа `(+7 123) 456-78-90`, но чаще все-таки остается за скобками `+7 (123) 456-78-90`.

Вообще что это такое в скобках? Я просто не в курсе. Если код страны это только например `+7` для России, то что значат следующие обычно 3 цифры (зачем-то ведь их отделяют)?

И наконец сколько вообще цифр бывает в разных частях номера? Точнее скажем так в каком диапазоне их количество? Например в последней части обычно 7 цифр для мобильных номеров и 6 для городских (в России), но как за рубежом я не знаю... А что со второй частью в скобках? И с кодом? От скольки и до скольки цифр там может быть?

Comment: Встречаются номера в 12 цифр, как вариант, можно сделать 2 маски для России `+7 (999) 999-99-99`, и если код не `+7`, то сделать интернациональную маску, что-то типа `+9 9999999999?9` (количество обязательных цифр условно, можно и другое, надо смотреть на номера более глубоко)

Comment: "+7" - это не код города. Это код РФ в международной сетке. Украина, к примеру, - "+3". А вот следующие цифры  включают код населённого пункта и номер в нём. К примеру: +7 861 96 x-xx-xx расшифровывается так: +7 - Россия, 861 - Краснодар, если последующий номер из 5 цифр,

Comment: иначе - Краснодарский край. 96 - Тихорецкий район или Тихорецк, последние 5 цифр: x-xx-xx - номер телефона в краснодарском крае, тихорецком районе. Скобки в номере писались ранее для Москвы, Питера и других крупных городов в том случае, если для звонка по городу, набирать их было не обязательно.

Comment: До недавнего времени в той же Москве. можно было набрать последние семь цифр номера, так как код города (495) - был один. Но вот из других городов в Москву можно было позвонить только набрав этот код. Теперь городских кодов по крайней мере два: 495 и 499 и их набирать стало обязательно. Скобки теперь пишут скорее по-традиции.

Comment: @Quazimorda Уточнение: у Украины код не "3", а "380". Собственно, код из одной цифры есть всего у двух стран в мире .

Comment: @Yaant Так точно, спасибо за поправку.

Comment: Пардон, я знаю что +7 - код страны. Это какая-то опечатка у меня была. :D

Comment: https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood/blob/master/README.md#phone-numbers

Comment: У двух стран? но не у России. В России коды +79,+78,+74

Answer (score 0):

В скобках обычно указывают код города или оператора в России. Скобки не обязательны, их используют для "удобства".

Вот ссылка на список массок по странам: http://www.itu.int/oth/T0202.aspx?parent=T0202

1. Ты можешь предлагать пользователю вводить номер с использованием
   маски, но в каждой стране своё написание и длина. Придется разбираться в вопросе более глубоко.
2. Отдельно выбираешь страну и отдельно вводишь оставшуюся часть
   номера, но тогда тебе в любом случае нужно узнать что как в каждой стране.
3. Поставить + за пределами input и разрешить только ввод цифр не
   запариваясь о количестве цифр.

Подумай нужно ли тебе тратить на это столько много времени или нет.

Comment: Ну во первых какая-то валидация все-равно нужна и номера могут быть не Российские. Во вторых уж лучше сразу делать качественно или ничего не делать (но зачем тогда работать?). Со скобками выглядит красивее и мне так больше нравится... Выбирать отдельно страну я не хочу - слишком муторно. Я скорее надеялся дать определенный диапазон для ввода, например код страны 1-5 цифр, код города примерно также, остальная часть номера допустим 5-15 цифр. Я только хотел более точно узнать эти диапазоны.

Comment: @DarkByte Многие сайты и мессенджеры предлагают выбрать страну, а потом уже вводить номер телефона. Страну можно попытаться угадать по локали браузера. + вводить не надо и скобки тоже - они очень опциональны.

Comment: https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood/blob/master/README.md#phone-numbers